# Is it possible to approximate any nonnegative Schwartz function by square of Schwartz functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation, schwartz-space

Let $f$ be a nonnegative Schwartz function on $n$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Then I wonder if it is possible to find a sequence of complex-valued Schwartz functions $f_n$ such that $\lvert f_n \rvert^2$ converges to $f$ in the Frechet topology of the Schwartz space.

I think it is plausible but cannot figure out how to prove / disprove.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried the usual mollification strategy, i.e. multiply $\sqrt f$ by a smooth cut-off function and take the convolution with a test function?

Comment: @MaoWao I tried but cannot establish convergence after taking the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For every $L>0$ let $\chi_1\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be the standard cut-off function such that $\varphi(t) =0$ for $\vert t \vert \geq 1$, $\varphi(0)=1$ and $\varphi^{(k)}(1)=0$ for all $k\geq 1$. Then we define for every $L\geq 0$ the cut-off function
$$ \varphi_L: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \varphi_L(t) = \begin{cases} 0,& \vert t \vert\geq L+1,  \\ 1,& \vert t \vert \leq L,\\ \varphi(t-\mathrm{sgn(t)L}),& L<\vert t \vert<L+1.  \end{cases} $$
One readily checks that $\varphi_L\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. We now define the cut-off function
$$ \chi_L:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \chi_L(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n \varphi_L(x_j). $$
It is easy to check that for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$ and all $L\geq 1$ we have
$$ \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \vert \partial^\alpha \chi_L(x) \vert = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \vert\partial^\alpha \chi_1(x) \vert < \infty. $$

The problem boils down to find a positive $g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\sqrt{g}\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Once we have found such a function, then we can define

$$ f_\varepsilon(x):=\sqrt{\chi_{1/\varepsilon}(x)f(x)+ \varepsilon g(x)}. $$

Define the semi-norms
$$ \Vert f \Vert_{\alpha, \beta} := \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \vert x^\beta \partial^\alpha f(x) \vert. $$

Since
\begin{align*}
 \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \vert \partial^\alpha \chi_{1/\epsilon}(x) \vert <\infty
\end{align*}
as noted above, we have
\begin{align*}
\lVert f_\epsilon^2 \rVert_{\alpha. \beta} <\infty
\end{align*}
for all $\alpha, \beta$, which implies that $f_\epsilon^2 \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Now, consider another Schwartz function
\begin{align*}
F_\epsilon:=(1-\chi_{1/\epsilon}) f
\end{align*}
Since $F_\epsilon$ is supported on $[\frac{1}{\epsilon}, \infty)^n \sqcup (-\infty, -\frac{1}{\epsilon}]^n$, the estimate
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \lvert x^{\beta}\partial^\alpha F_\epsilon(x) \rvert \leq \Bigl \lvert  \Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i \Bigr) x^{\beta}\partial^\alpha F_\epsilon(x) \Bigr \rvert=\lvert x^{\beta+(1,\cdots,1)}\partial^\alpha F_\epsilon(x) \rvert
\end{align*}
holds for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \Vert F_\epsilon \Vert_{\alpha, \beta} \leq \Vert F_\epsilon \Vert_{\alpha, \beta+(1, \dots, 1)}
\end{align*}

We also observed above that the supremum of $\partial^\alpha \chi_L$ does not depend on $L$. Hence $\Vert F_\epsilon \Vert_{\alpha, \beta+(1, \dots, 1)}$ does not depend on $\epsilon$, implying
\begin{align*}
\Vert f_\varepsilon^2 - f \Vert_{\alpha, \beta}
\leq \Vert F_\epsilon \Vert_{\alpha, \beta} + \varepsilon \Vert g \Vert_{\alpha, \beta}
\leq \epsilon^n \Vert F_\epsilon \Vert_{\alpha, \beta+(1, \dots, 1)} + \varepsilon \Vert g \Vert_{\alpha, \beta} \to 0^+ \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0^+
\end{align*}
for all $\alpha,\beta$. That is, $f_\varepsilon^2 \to f$ in the Fréchet topology of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Lastly, we need to check if $f_\epsilon \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. However, because $g$ is assumed to be positive, it is clear that $f_\epsilon$ is smooth on whole $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, $f_\varepsilon (x)=\sqrt{\varepsilon g(x)}$ for $\vert x \vert > 1/\varepsilon$ so that
\begin{equation}
\lvert x^\beta \partial^\alpha f_\epsilon(x) \rvert \leq \sup_{ \lvert x \rvert \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} } \lvert x^\beta \partial^\alpha f_\epsilon(x) \rvert + \sqrt{\epsilon}\sup_{ \lvert x \rvert > \frac{1}{\epsilon} } \lvert x^\beta \partial^\alpha \sqrt{g}(x) \rvert
\end{equation}
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\lVert f_\epsilon \rVert_{\alpha, \beta} < \infty
\end{equation}
for all $\alpha, \beta$, implying $f_\epsilon \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Note that $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ does the job as $\sqrt{g(x)}= e^{-x^2/2}$ is again Schwartz.

Comment: I do not clearly see how you conclude that $f_\epsilon$ is a Schwartz function just by inspecting $\lvert x \rvert > 1/\epsilon$.

Comment: Plus, how do you know that $f^2_\epsilon \to f$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? What about partial derivatives of $\chi_{1/\epsilon}$?

Comment: Well, Schwartz functions need to be smooth and certain suprema must be finite. Clearly our function is smooth on the interior of $B(0,\varepsilon^{-1})$ and due to everything being smooth, it only contributes a finite quantity to the supremum (thus, we don't care about it). I have changed the cut-off function in such a way that it is easy to see that the derivatives do not depend on $L$. Is it clear now?

Comment: OK, so $f_\epsilon$ is smooth on whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we don't have to worry about the $\lvert x \rvert \leq \epsilon^{-1}$ because it is compact.

Comment: And due to the given form of $f_\epsilon$ on the "outside" region $\lvert x \rvert \geq \epsilon^{-1}$, we conclude that $f_\epsilon$ is smooth and its Schwartz seminorms (on whole $\mathbb{R}^n$) are finite.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only thing we need here is that the expression in the square root is positive to ensure that it is smooth.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Then the next issue: I do not still see why each partial derivative of $\chi_{1/\epsilon}f$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to that of $f$, especially if the partial deriavtives of $\chi_{L}$ do NOT depend on $L$.

Comment: The supremum does not depend on $\varepsilon$, simply because we are only translating, about which the supremum of the derivatives does not care. I have added some details. Also I have to leave now, I have other things to do.

Comment: Thank you. I fully understand now.