# $\sqrt{ f(x) + \alpha e^{-\lVert x \rVert^2}}$ is a Schwartz function for any nonnegative Schwartz $f$ and $\alpha>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, schwartz-space

This question has been motivated by [original](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4870751/is-it-possible-to-approximate-any-nonnegative-schwartz-function-by-square-of-sch?noredirect=1#comment10384172_4870751) and comments therein.

Let $f$ be a nonnegative Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$ be fixed. Then, I wonder if
\begin{equation}
F(x):=\sqrt{ f(x) + \alpha e^{-\lVert x \rVert^2}}
\end{equation}
is also a Schwartz function.

At least $F$ is well-defined, looks smooth and decays to $0$ as $\lVert x \rVert \to \infty$. Also, by somehow computing partial derivatives of arbitrary order, it seems possible to show that $F$ is indeed Schwartz. However, is there any more elegant way to show that $F$ is a Schwartz function?

Could anyone provide some insight?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145789/a-schwartz-function-problem) shows that for $g(x) := e^{-x^2}(e^{-x^2} + \sin^2 x),$ $\sqrt{g}$ is not Schwartz. We can bootstrap this to get a counterexample for your case if we can tweak $g$ so that $g - \alpha e^{-x^2}$ is nonnegative. To this end, first note that scaling $g$ doesn't change the main property, so we might as well assume $\alpha = 1$. Then just define $h(x) = g(x/\sqrt 2)$ and $f(x) = h(x) - e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you for your insightful counterexample. Well... this thwarts my attempt at [original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4870751/is-it-possible-to-approximate-any-nonnegative-schwartz-function-by-square-of-sch).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Perhaps, could you provide any insight to the [original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4870751/is-it-possible-to-approximate-any-nonnegative-schwartz-function-by-square-of-sch) as well?